# Why can't I use rgba in CSS Variable?

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

I'm trying to create this variable in SCSS file. But that doesn't work. Where am I doing wrong?

```
--orange: #fda63c;
--orange-light: rgba(var(--orange), 0.15);
```

Doesn't works this also:

```
--orange: #fda63c;
background-color: rgba(var(--orange), 0.15);
```

Comment: rgba() expect rgba format value like rgba(01,02,03, 0.15) but you stored in your variable hexa format (#fda63c). This can be an issue here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You won't be able to pass a function into `rgba`, but `rgba` will accept a variable containing the `rgb` value of a color.

```css
:root {
--orange: 253, 166, 60;
--orange-light: rgba(var(--orange), 0.15);  
}


p {
  color: var(--orange-light);
}
```

```html
<p>Hello orange world</p>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ck96e5gw/)

Comment: I use a variable with `rgb(253, 166, 60)` and it doesn't work, as your answer, I need to make a variable containing only rgb numbers, I felt I'm blind because I didn't notice your answer omit rgb in the variable. Thanks

Comment: @stefancho Use the number group without the rgb function `253, 166, 60`. I don't understand how the comma separated numbers translate/work, but they do.